# Java 11 Compact Strings magic behind char[] to byte[]

Tags: java, string, ascii, java-9, extended-ascii

I been reading about encoding Unicode Java 9 compact Strings in the last two days i am getting quite well. But there is something that i dont understand.

About byte data type

1). Is a 8-bit storage ranges from -128 to 127

Questions

1). Why Java didn't implement it like char unsigned 16 bits? i mean it would be in a  range of 0.256 because from 0 to 127 only can i hold a Ascii value but what would happen if i set the value 200 a extended ascii would overflow to -56.

2). Does the negative value mean something i mean i have try a simple example using Java 11

```
final char value = (char)200;//in byte would overflow
final String stringValue = new String(new char[]{value});
System.out.println(stringValue);//THE SAME VALUE OF JAVA 8
```

I have checked the String.value variable and i see a byte array of

```
System.out.println(value[0]);//-56
```

The same questions like before arise does the -56 mean something i mean the (negative value) in other languages this overflow is detected to return to the value 200? How can Java know that -56 value is the same as 200 in char.

I have try hardest examples like codepoint 128048 and i see in String.value variable a array of bytes like this.

```
0 = 61 
1 = -40
2 = 48
3 = -36
```

I know this codepoint takes 4 bytes but i get it how is transformed char[] to byte[] **but i dont know how String handle this byte[] data.**

Sorry if this question is simple and sorry any typing english is not my natural language thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why Java didn't implement it like char unsigned 16 bits? i mean it would be in a range of 0.256 because from 0 to 127 only can i hold a Ascii value but what would happen if i set the value 200 a extended ascii would overflow to -56.

Java’s primitive data types were settled with Java 1.0 a quarter century ago. The compact strings were introduced in Java 9, less than two years ago. This new feature, which is merely an implementation detail, did not justify fundamental changes at Java’s type system.

Besides that, you are looking at one *interpretation* of the data stored in a byte. For the sake of representing iso-latin-1 units, it is entirely irrelevant whether interpreting the same data as Java’s built-in signed `byte` would result in a positive or negative number.

Likewise Java’s I/O API allows reading a file into a `byte[]` array and write `byte[]` arrays back to files and these two operations are already sufficient to copy a file losslessly, regardless of its file format which would be relevant when interpreting its content.

So the following works since Java 1.1:

```
byte[] bytes = "È".getBytes("iso-8859-1");
System.out.println(bytes[0]);
System.out.println(bytes[0] & 0xff);
```

```
-56
200
```

The two numbers, `-56` and `200` are just different interpretations of the bit pattern `11001000` whereas the iso-latin-1 interpretation of a `byte` containing the bit pattern `11001000` is the character `È`.

A `char` value is also just an interpretation of a two byte quantity, i.e. as UTF-16 code unit. Likewise, a `char[]` array is a sequence of bytes in the computer’s memory with a standard interpretation.

We can also interpret other byte sequences this way.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(128048);
byte[] array = new byte[4];
StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE.newEncoder()
    .encode(CharBuffer.wrap(sb), ByteBuffer.wrap(array), true);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

will print the value you’ve seen, `[61, -40, 48, -36]`.

The advantage of using a `byte[]` array inside the `String` class is, that now, the interpretation can be chosen, to use iso-latin-1 when all characters are representable with this encoding or utf-16 otherwise.

The possible numeric interpretations are irrelevant to the string. However, when you ask “How can Java know that -56 value is the same as 200”, you should ask yourself, how does it know that the bit pattern `11001000` of a `byte` is `-56` in the first place?

```
System.out.println(value[0]);
```

bears an actually expensive operation, compared to ordinary computer arithmetic, the conversion of a `byte` (or an `int`) to a `String`. This conversion operation is often overlooked as it has been defined as the default way of printing a `byte`, but is not more natural than a conversion to a `String` interpreting the value as an unsigned quantity. For further reading, I recommend [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: Why Little Endian? I try your code with Ascii and UTF-8 and Utf-16 and no match my array [61,-40,48,-36]

Comment: You have to decide for either LE or BE as otherwise, `StandardCharsets.UTF_16` will write a byte order mark. I just used LE, because the result matches the values you’ve written in the question then. It might be that the Java developers decided for LE because that helps the JVM to optimize the access to read the UTF-16 units as two-byte words in one instruction (on the commonly used x86 platform).

Comment: thanks by your patiente! I just thought that just because my array was generated by java.lang.String in UTF-16 mode would match the array generated by UTF-16 in your code but nope.

Comment: Are we still talking about the `[61, -40, 48, -36]` of your question? This is precisely what my code produces. What do you get?

Comment: Btw, I just verified that the `String` implementation does indeed choose the UTF-16 byte order to match the native byte order which confirms my theory about enabling JVM side optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

This is because not all bytes in a string are interpreted the same. This depends to the string's [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Example:

- if a string is an UTF-8 string, its characters will be 8-bits in size.
- in an UTF-16 string, its characters will be 16-bits in size.
- *etc...*

This means, if the string is to be represented as UTF-8, the characters will be made by reading 1 byte at a time; if 16-bits, the characters will made by reading 2 bytes at a time.

Look at this code: a single byte array `data` is transformed to string using UTF-8 and UTF-16.

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {97, 98, 99, 100};
System.out.println(new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println(new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
```

The output of this code is:

```
abcd // 4 bytes = 4 chars, 1 byte per char
慢捤  // 4 bytes = 2 chars, 2 byte per char
```

Going back to the question, what motivated the developers to do so is to reduce memory footprint on strings. Not all strings uses all the 16-bits a `char` offers.

EDIT: [Code here](https://ideone.com/M4vXcz)

Comment: Thanks but in Latin-1 in my code -56 is getting transform into what?

Comment: Try to use ```Byte.toUnsignedInt(value[0])```

Comment: Yep but how java.lang.String handles that negative byte values internally? i mean how String creates a String with those negative values.?

Comment: "UTF-8 string" is a bit confusing because all text datatypes in Java use the UTF-16 character encoding. (Same for VB4/5/6/A/Script, JavaScript, .NET, …). And a `String` doesn't have bytes.